# PHP & Jquery to send email

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I am trying to get my form to use jquery to send an email. I know email is server side, so I have connected my jquery to php, and what I want to do is get an alert back after the email has been sent from the php file, but I don't get any alerts back as of right now.

```
<!-- JS FILE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/includes.js"></script>

<!-- HTML FORM -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
<form class="modal-content animate" action="#" method="POST">
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close">&times;</span>
</div>

<div class="container_form">
  <span><b>Account Information</b></span>
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email_name" required>  
  <input id="lbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Java Script Code:

```
$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function
    $('#lbutton').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : './helpers/sendmail.php',           
            data: {
                action: "lost_info",
                email   : $('#email').val()
                },
            success:function (data) {
                if (data == "sent")
                    alert("An email has been sent to you, please check your email");
                else
                    alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
            }      
        });     
    });
});
```

PHP Code for testing:

```
<?php
  echo "sent";
?>
```

Comment: Is your ajax executed? is the URL correct? What's inside `data`?

Comment: Add an error handler to the ajax call, and open the console

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @empiric the URL is correct, data would just be the echo back of "sent", but it doesn't get sent back.

Comment: @Jayce you say `data` would be, but what is it actually? e.g. when you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have used <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> for the library. It is on web-server, nothing shows in console.

Comment: If no alerts are showing, you have an error, the success handler never executes. It could be the event handler never executes as `#lbutton` sounds like a button, and buttons have no `submit` events, only forms do, or it could be something else.

Comment: `So I am trying to get my form to use jquery to send an email. I know email is client side`. Actually, email is serverside. Are you sure the path to the `PHP` file is correct?

Comment: Also, remove the action from the `AJAX` when you're just using `echo "sent"`, as I suppose that a function.

Comment: @lonut I was previously using a php file in that same directory, and it worked fine, I am just going for a smoother look now instead of having multiple pages open.

Comment: have you check url path : './helpers/sendmail.php' is corrently send data to your php page ?. have you debug using $_POST or $_RESPONSE that ajax data receive ?